# Android: ListView Flicker effect. Any hints on how to get rid of this?

Tags: android, listview, transparent, flicker

For some reason, whenever I scroll through my list of items, the background inside my listview disappears and reappears giving rise to a "flicker" effect which I don't really want. I've tried the suggestion at: [How to make a ListView transparent in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377336/android-make-listview-transparent) but it doesn't work for some reason. Any suggestions?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/screenLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/title_background"
            android:text="@string/whatsnew_title"
            >
        </TextView>
        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >
        </ListView>     
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Did you include `android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"`? It's the most important part of the proposed fix. I've just tried your code (obviously not an exact reproduction, as you're using references to project-specific resources) with it, and it seems to work.

[This post on the Android Developers blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html) should be of your interest.

Comment: Awesome... You wouldn't believe me... I tried attaching cacheColorHint but every resource I found said android:cacheColorHint="#000000" (notice the number of zeroes apparently saying nothing about alpha)... And now it works exactly as I wanted it to... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This can also be achieved from Java (code) side: `listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);`

Answer (score 1):

Check your theme.xml for `<item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>`. If you have it - remove it. I think one of the popular resources gives this line as example (that's how I got mine).

Comment: I actually don't have a custom theme.xml. Are you suggesting that I create one?

Comment: You may try that - I had a similar issue with my preferences screen (which is ListView)  but then - I did have custom theme.xml and the entry I have in my answer