# android-listview problem with transparent cells

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to make a listview with semi-transparent cells (some sort of blue with 25% opacity).

The listview is created correctly but, when i perform an scroll motion(I press and drag down or up) the list seems to activate some sort of selection mechanism witch applies a black and opaque background  to the list.

Any Idea how I can get rid of this?

Below is the code and the two screens:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@drawable/background">
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/my_health_title">
</ImageView>
<ListView android:id="@+id/health" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>
```

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/health_title" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#46727c"
    android:textSize="14sp" android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" android:layout_marginLeft="30px"
    android:text="Blood presure Profile">
</TextView>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/health_gauge"
    android:layout_width="250dp" android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">
</LinearLayout>

<TextView android:id="@+id/health_description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#46727c" android:textSize="12sp" android:textStyle="normal"
    android:layout_marginTop="150px" android:layout_marginLeft="30px"
    android:text="Looks Goood">
</TextView>

<ImageView android:id="@+id/health_details"
    android:background="@drawable/home_arrow_icon_margin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true">
</ImageView>
```

[normal list](http://img97.imageshack.us/img97/4786/deviceu.png)

[selected efect](http://img541.imageshack.us/img541/3630/device2u.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the **android:cacheColorHint** to **#00000000** on your ListView.

Notice that the color code is an 8 digit code (*#AARRGGBB*), which means that the first two digits represents the alpha of the color. (If you set it to a 6 digit, #000000 it won't help, because it will be still opaque. For more info on color codes click [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html)).

Your list view should look like this:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/health" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000">
</ListView>
```

More details and explanation can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html).

Comment: Setting  android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" worked. <p> Thanks Sanj and bbalazs

Answer (score 3):

I was having a nightmare with a similar problem. But I was adding the ListView dynamically, and

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

didn't work in this case. The solution:

Don't add ListView dynamically, cacheColorHint will not work

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: You can set programmatically with this: listView.setCacheColorHint(0)