# Android Menu transparent

Tags: android, android-layout

Can i make the menu transparent(make the white not visible)

I created an xml for the menu.

[image]

Here i added the image as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/done"
         android:icon="@drawable/base"
           />
</menu>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593529/android-customize-applications-menu-e-g-background-color

Answer (score 1):

If it is a popup window, use

```
popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(null)
```

This works like charm

Answer (score 0):

You probably can use:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

As described here: [How to make a ListView transparent in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377336/how-to-make-a-listview-transparent-in-android)

Comment: frnd their is no "background" property in <items>