# ListView transparency

Tags: android, listview, background, transparency

I have a problem setting a list's background with transparency. I'm unable to set transparency.

Here is my code:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/players_list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/players_text" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" android:background="#00000000">
</ListView>
```

In my activity:

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.players_list);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    HashMap<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map1.put("field1", "John Doe");
    map1.put("field2", "2342");
    mylist.add(map1);
    HashMap<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map2.put("field1", "Simina Dorin");
    map2.put("field2", "10000");
    mylist.add(map2);

    SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist,
            R.layout.online_players_row,
            new String[] { "field1", "field2" }, new int[] {
                    R.id.players_text, R.id.score_text });

    list.setAdapter(mSchedule);
```

Any advices?

---

Found the problem:
I had to set my list's row layout with a background like: android:background="#80439197"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377336/how-to-make-a-listview-transparent-in-android

Comment: what is the problem that you are facing? what is the result that you are expecting?

Comment: http://community.developer.motorola.com/t5/Android-App-Development-for/ListView-transparent-background/td-p/13650

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: I've posted a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560448/android-transparent-colored-listviews-with-background/38368774#38368774

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377336/how-to-make-a-listview-transparent-in-android) and explained [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html)

android:background="@color/transparent"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"