# Android: Transparent Colored ListViews with Background

Tags: android, android-listview

I have  a doubt I have a listview and below it there is a background with a image. I would like to have the lists with a transparent color in order to see the image in the background with the ListViews color. I have tried using a selector but it just applies to the select item i the listview.
Maybe it is not very clear so for that purpose I attach the following picture where the listview and the background is shown: [image: http://www.ingens-networks.com/blog/image.axd?picture=2012%2f4%2fdevice-2012-04-27-132332.png]

As you can see the item background is with color but the image is still visible

Thank you very much

Comment: Have you tried creating a Custom list item?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377336/how-to-make-a-listview-transparent-in-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add following property in ListView...

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

it is for transparent background of ListView.
More detail see [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setCacheColorHint%28int%29).

Comment: Thanks, used your asnwer as well as this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285961/how-to-make-a-background-transparent-20-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an image editor to edit the opacity of the image/shape/gradient/whatever that you're using for the rows. I use Gimp because it's free. Here's what you need to do in Gimp: Go to the 'Layers - Brushes' window. Right-click the image layer and 'Add Alpha Channel'. Then just dial down the Opacity using the number picker (located above the layer) and File -> Export the image. Add this image to your project. Set it as the background for the List View **rows**. Then set the background for the List View itself to whatever you want to take up the entire background behind the List View.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve this with the RecyclerView by adding this line of code to the 'onBindViewHolder' method in the 'RecyclerView.Adapter' class:

```
((RelativeLayout) holder.itemView).getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FFFFFF"));
```

Bear in mind that the view returned by the above cast expression is an 'android.support.v7.widget.CardView' that contains the list item layout