# Transparent Listview over google Map android

Tags: android, google-maps, listview, android-listview

In my application I need to create a transparent listview over google map. I am using toggle button to open and close listview. When listview is visible it should be transparent so that google map should be visible/semi-visible.

For this part there are three layouts.
1. custom_cluster_mapview.xml
2. bottomlayout.xml
3. map_list_view_row

1. **custom_cluster_mapview.xml**

   ```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:materialdesign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.gc.materialdesign"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".map.MapView" >

   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

       <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/mapLayout"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="1" >

           <fragment
               android:id="@+id/mycustomemap"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
       </LinearLayout>

       <include layout="@layout/bottomlayout" />




   </LinearLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
2. **bottomlayout.xml**

   ```
      <LinearLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

       android:id="@+id/outerLayout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:weightSum="2"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       >



           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:orientation="vertical"
               >
           <ToggleButton
               android:layout_width="40dp"
               android:layout_height="40dp"
               android:background="@drawable/up_arrow"
               android:textOff=""
               android:textOn=""
               android:id="@+id/toggleButtonListView"
               android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
           </LinearLayout>

       <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/mapListViewSlider"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:visibility="gone"
           android:layout_weight="1.95"
           android:orientation="vertical">


           <CheckBox
               android:id="@+id/sort_distance"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="Sort By Distance"/>
           <ListView
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:dividerHeight="5dp"
               android:divider="@color/red"
               android:id="@+id/map_listview"/>
           </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
   ```

**3. map_list_view_row.xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/map_list_view_tv1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/label_name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/map_list_view_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/map_list_view_tv1"
                android:text="abcde"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/map_list_view_tv2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/label_category" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/map_list_view_category"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/map_list_view_tv2"
                android:text="abcde" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/map_list_view_tv3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/label_location" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/map_list_view_location"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/map_list_view_tv3"
                android:text="abcde" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/map_list_view_tv4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:text="@string/label_distance" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/map_list_view_distance"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/map_list_view_tv4"
                android:text="abcde" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/map_list_view_imageView"
        android:background="@drawable/med"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Following is the picture when map is loaded
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtizG.png

At bottom of the screen there is up arrow button. I want to make background of that transparent. So that only arrow is visible without any background. When I click on the arrow listView is shown. Like below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUFZz.png

How to make listView transparent so that the google map is visible/semi-visible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure but can you try : android:background="@null"

Comment: Please add it to the listview itself

Comment: Bhavesh N gave the solution. It is working.\

Comment: Great :D will keep noted in case I need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this line in relative layout not in Linear layout

```
 <include layout="@layout/bottomlayout" />
```

and set all color in this layout is semi tratnsparent.

Comment: Semi transparent in bottom layout ? I have tried all the things. I have made activity transparent with android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent". But Nothing happened.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.
Can you explain this ?
Once again. Thanks.

Comment: Bhavesh N can you explain why it worked ? What was the mistake ?

Comment: You have put include tag inside the linear layout,  so it is always show below the map, so when you click on arrow  your entire map moves up.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this attribute in your listview

```
 android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
 android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377336/how-to-make-a-listview-transparent-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` has a *transparent/translucent* background by default, and so all default Android widgets. This implies that when ListView redraws its children, it has to blend the children with the window's background.

To solve your problem, all you have to do is either disable the cache color hint optimization, if you use a non-solid color background, or set the hint to the appropriate solid color value. This can be dome from code or preferably from XML.

### XML:

```
android:cacheColorHint="#0000"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

### Code:

```
listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: Holmes. I tried edited version as well. bhavesh N solution works fine.